# Avoid JQuery being applied to _layout View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view page with following script at the bottom

```
   @section AssignSpeakerScripts
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("a").click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var v = $(this).closest("div");
                    v.slideUp("slow");
                })
            });
    </script>
    }
```

I also have following entry in my layout page

```
@RenderSection("AssignSpeakerScripts", required: false)
```

Which is simple enough, i.e. on click of anchor tag it rolls-up the closest div. I have menu in the layout page which again have anchor tags inside the divs. When the page loads it achieves what I want but the problem is even the anchor tags in the menu rolls up. The way I can avoid this is by using the id as shown below, but I want to use some other cleaner option if available.

```
@section AssignSpeakerScripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("a").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var v = $(this).closest("div");
                var mId = v.attr('id');
                if(mId=='divMaster'||mId=='divDetail')
                v.slideUp("slow");
            })
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check [jquery.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) `$(this).closest("div").not("#divMaster, #divDetail");`